# Installing Visual Studio 2008 SP1 problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 but it tells me that "Previous releases of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008: Failed". I downloaded Visual Studio 2008 SP1 from here [VS2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en?), installed it (it said that the installation was successful), restarted the machine, but nothing has changed in Visual Studio Help -> About and the SQL Server 2008 Setup still tells me that Visual Studio 2008 is not upgraded to the SP1.

Does anybody know what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you slipstreamed the latest service pack into the SQL server installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install SQL Server first, before Visual Studio. This should remedy the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to uninstall SQL Server 2008 and use the Visual Studio 2008 installer to install SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I think the problem is in my VS2008 version - now it is '9.0.2 RTM' and I am trying to upgrade it to '9.0.3 SP' but SP1 patch doesn't upgrade it. Is there a way to move from version 9.0.2 RTM to 9.0.3 SP?

Comment: how is that helpful? If I want to install SQL Server 2008 Developer edition, how will I manage that through the VS installer?

Comment: @Randolph Potter: because the VS installer should propose to install SQL Server if it is not installed.

Comment: the version of SQL in Visual Studio is SQL Express. What if @etarvt wants a different version?